# Deploying Rails app to heroku error (sqlite3->Postgresql)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, deployment, heroku

I'm suddenly getting an "Application Error" when I deploy some changes to my rails app on heroku. And not really sure why and I can't find a proper solution.

Here are the logs:

```
   2012-10-22T20:05:26+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
   2012-10-22T20:06:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
   2012-10-22T20:06:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
   2012-10-22T20:06:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle e
   xec rails server -p 28612`
   2012-10-22T20:06:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
   2012-10-22T20:06:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
   .rb:90:in `select'
   2012-10-22T20:06:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-22 20:06:57] ERROR SignalExceptio
   n: SIGTERM
   2012-10-22T20:07:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKI
   LL
   2012-10-22T20:07:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least on
   e process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
   2012-10-22T20:07:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
   2012-10-22T20:07:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process
   failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
   2012-10-22T20:07:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
   2012-10-22T20:07:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
   2012-10-22T20:07:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
   2012-10-22T20:07:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
   2012-10-22T20:08:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle e
   xec rails server -p 26859`
   2012-10-22T20:09:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process
   failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
   2012-10-22T20:09:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
   2012-10-22T20:09:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
   2012-10-22T20:09:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
   2012-10-22T20:09:27+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET www.thr
   illengine.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=`
```

In development it works fine.

**Update:**

40 min later everything is back to normal and working. Strange, considering that I didn't really do nothing.
Anyone else experiencing something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does the gem file has pg gem?
2. did u migrate your db on production DB?
3. does the deploy give any errors?

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. Yes; 3. Nope.

Comment: It was probably the downtime at Amazon AWS. maybe it was nothing at your side !

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/22/aws-ec2-issues-in-north-virginia-affect-heroku-reddit-and-others-heroku-still-down/